# PHP regex: what is "class at offset 0"?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to strip all punctuation out of a string using a simple regular expression and the php preg_replace function, although I get the following error:

> Compilation failed: POSIX named classes are supported only within a class at offset 0

I guess this means I can't use POSIX named classes outside of a class at offset 0. My question is, what does it means when it says "within a class at offset 0 "?

```
$string = "I like: perl";    

if (eregi('[[:punct:]]', $string))  
    $new = preg_replace('[[:punct:]]', ' ', $string); echo $new;
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of tags, I was getting an error when tying to tag this question. "You can't add new tags, please use existing tags".. How am I supposed to know what that means?

Comment: I fixed the tags.  I think there's a bug in your program: did you mean for the echo to occur outside or inside of the if block?

Comment: I think you need some level of reputation to create a new tag.  But the error message is poor.  Maybe you could suggest a change to the UserVoice feedback site listed below.  VVVVVV

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [`preg_*` functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) expect [Perl compatible regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) with delimiters. So try this:

```
preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', ' ', $string)
```

Comment: Fantastic, not only does this solve my problem, but I also learnt something new about how preg_* works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE: The `g` modifier is not needed with PHP's `PCRE` implementation!**

In addition to [Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475159/php-regex-what-is-class-at-offset-0#475170), use the `g` modifier to replace *all* occurances of punctuation:

```
preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/g', ' ', $string)
//                         ^
```

From [Johnathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) (see comments):

```
> [The g modifier] means "Global" -- i.e., find all existing matches. Without it, regex functions will stop searching after the first match.
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to the complexities of regular expressions, what "specifically" is the definition of 'g'? I'd assume from you've said that it's a way of telling the regexp to be recursive?

Comment: @chris: It means "Global" -- i.e., find all existing matches. Without it, regex functions will stop searching after the first match.

Comment: @Lonowski, thanks; I have updated my answer with your information.

Comment: /g means global, which tells regex to replace all instances.

echo "What's up?"|sed "s/[[:punct:]]/ /"

What s up?

echo "What's up?"|sed "s/[[:punct:]]/ /g"

What s up

However, strager's wrong.  preg_replace is /default/ global.

echo preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', ' ', "What's up?");

What s up

Comment: In this aspect the PHP implementation is not really following the Perl standard. The preg_replace() function always replaces all matches.

Comment: Wow, that comment looks bad with all the spacing screwed up.  Oh well.

Comment: @Flaschen, Gumbo: I did not know that!  I guess there's a few bugs in some regular expressions I've written in the past, then!

Comment: There’s a list of modifiers that are supported: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

An explanation of *why* you're getting that error: PCRE uses Perl's loose definition of what a delimiter is. Your outer `[]`s look like valid delimiters to it, causing it to read `[:punct:]` as the regex part.

(Oh, and avoid the `ereg` functions if you can - they're not going to be included in PHP 5.3.)

Comment: Is there an alternative to ereg_replace for what I'm doing?

Comment: @chris, He said ereg.  You're using preg_replace.  You're also using eregi (which isn't necessary, really, in this situation) which is what @Ant was talking about.

Comment: Sorry, moment of zero concentrtion. I see what he's saying now.

Answer (score 0):

I just added g to the regexp as suggested in one of the anwers, it did the opposite of wahts expected and DIDN'T filter out the punctuation, turns out preg_replace doesnt require g as it's global/recursive in the first place