# loadXML unhandleable error

Tags: php, xml

I'm using PEAR [XML_Feed_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Feed_Parser).
I have some [bad xml](http://feeds.feedburner.com/bishop-it/LaoT) that I give to it and get error.

```
DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE8 0xCF 0xD3 0xD4 in Entity, line: 7
```

*It's actually html in wrong encoding - KOI8-R.*

It's ok to get error but I can't handle it!

When I create new XML_Feed_Parser instance with

    $feed = new XML_Feed_Parser($xml);

it calls to __construct() that looks like that

```
$this->model = new DOMDocument;
if (! $this->model->loadXML($feed)) {
    if (extension_loaded('tidy') && $tidy) {
        /* tidy stuff */
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Invalid input: this is not valid XML');
}
```

Where we can see that if loadXML() failed then it throw exception.

I want to catch error from loadXML() to skip bad XMLs and notify user. So i wrapped my code with try-catch like that

```
try
{
    $feed = new XML_Feed_Parser($xml);
    /* ... */
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Feed invalid: '.$e->getMessage();
    return False;
}
```

But even after that I get that error

```
DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE8 0xCF 0xD3 0xD4 in Entity, line: 7
```

I've read about loadXML() and found that

> If an empty string is passed as the source, a warning will be generated. This warning is not generated by libxml and cannot be handled using libxml's error handling functions.

But somehow instead of warning i get error that halts my application. I've written my error handler and I saw that this is really warning ($errno is 2).

So i see 2 solutions:

1. Revert warnings to warnings - do not
   treat them like errors. (Google
   doesn't help me here). After that
   handle False returned from loadXML.
2. Somehow catch that error.

Any help?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-loa

Comment: @marek-sebera kinda duplicate. I've tried to convert with iconv. But mb_detect_encoding doesn't detect encoding:-) It tells me that my bad xml is UTF-8 which is obviously not true (it's KOI8-R)

Comment: Interesting. When I launch loadXML with that broken xml in console it gives me warnings and I can't catch False from it. Maybe it's something wrong with apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` solved my problem. It made libxml to use normal errors so i can catch False from loadXML().

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$this->model = new DOMDocument;
$converted = mb_convert_encoding($feed, 'UTF-8', 'KOI8-R');
if (! $this->model->loadXML($converted)) {
if (extension_loaded('tidy') && $tidy) {
    /* tidy stuff */
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception('Invalid input: this is not valid XML');
}
```

or you can do it without need to modify XML_Feed_Parser like this:

```
$xml = mb_convert_encoding($loaded_xml, 'UTF-8', 'KOI8-R');
$feed = new XML_Feed_Parser($xml);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also it break my good XMLs in UTF-8 converting them to mess.

Comment: Yeah, it's not used to convert UTF8->UTF8 just for this case, so maybe you should add some exception for this, some option in feed setting.