# PHP simplexml_load_string not working

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML String retrieved from a XML file. I can't access the file directly using `simplexml_load_file()`.  Reason is I have to get this through Amazon S3 getObject(). When I `echo` the string I can see the out put as a real XML file. But when I try to load it to a XML object using bellow code it doesn't work. The variable `$s3Data` exactly contain the XML content in the given link.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($s3Data);
```

I need your help to figure this out. The XML string I am getting is available here.

http://mediatheques-aphp.bibliomedias.net/12.xml

**EDIT**

I created the XML string and tested. Now I get following errors. How can I fix these.

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 12: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate
>   encoding ! Bytes: 0xEF 0x76 0x65 0x3C in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\voxmedia\application\modules\import\controllers\NaiveController.php
>   on line 1458
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   2009 naïve in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\voxmedia\application\modules\import\controllers\NaiveController.php
>   on line 1458
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^
>   in C:\Program
>   Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\voxmedia\application\modules\import\controllers\NaiveController.php
>   on line 1458

OK Now I feel the issue is with sort of string encoding or something. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: it "doesnt work" is never enough information. at least provide the error message.

Comment: Hi. There is no error message. My code work with other XML String. Please don't think about a file. Just think that you have a php string variable which has the content of given URL. `$s3Data` is a string variable which contains things in the given XML file. Don't think about getObject() etc...

Comment: I modified my question with latest update. Please check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input is not proper UTF-8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-lo)

Comment: It's looks like possible duplicate. But their answers `utf8_encode() didn't work for me. I've put my own answer with the way I fixed it. Thanks Gordon for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find an answer to my question with a small workaround. `simplexml_load_string()` continuously displayed encoding errors. So I used `simplexml_load_file()` as bellow. I've saved the file in to local location and then load with `simplexml_load_file()`.

```
$tempLocalPath = "temp/data.xml";
file_put_contents($tempLocalPath, $s3Data);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($tempLocalPath);
```

However still I don't understan why `simplexml_load_string()` couldn't parse the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

`simplexml_load_string` and `simplexml_load_file` are buggy and don't work well on XML with a complex markup.
I tried both functions to parse some VALID XML SOAP responses and could not even get an error message. 
I had to use `DOMDocument` instead (worked like a charm).

Here is how we suppose to check simplexml for errors (if you are lucky to see errors, not just "false" returned from function)

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData); //or simplexml_load_file

foreach( libxml_get_errors() as $error ) {

    print_r($error);

}
```

Comment: Oh goodness gracious! I've been trying for hours to load the result of a SOAP request string with `simplexml_load_string` and it insisted on just not working (without any error). Thanks for the `DOMDocument` reference, made my day!

Answer (score 1):

if your xml is soap request. You can try this

```
$testxml= htmlentities(strval($xml));
```

Answer (score -1):

When you `echo` a variable which is actually an object its [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)() method is called to convert the object to a string but when you pass the object to function the object issn't converted.

Use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( (string)$s3Data);
```

To cast the $s3Data object to a string.

PS:
Use var_dump($s3Data) and var_dump($xml) to debug the contents of a variable instead of echo.

Comment: No casting didn't work. I tried that. My code work with other XML String. Please don't think about a file. Just think that you have a php string variable which has the content of given file.

Comment: Strange using $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://mediatheques-aphp.bibliomedias.net/12.xml')); works on my machine, no xml errors whatsoever.

Comment: Quoting the OP: *I have to get this through Amazon S3 getObject().*

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Comment: This is the full version of what he's doing and it helps in no way. simplexml_load_string is bugged.