# Reading XML Content from url into PHP not working

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read the content of this xml url into my php code but it is failing. But if I go to the XML url directly on the browser (http://www.w3schools.com/Php/note.xml) it shows, Here is my code :

```
  $xml=simplexml_load_string("http://www.w3schools.com/Php/note.xml") or die("Error: Fail to Load Xml");
  echo $xml->to . "<br>";
  echo $xml->from . "<br>";
  echo $xml->heading . "<br>";
  echo $xml->body;
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290145/php-simplexml-load-string-not-working

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$xml->{"to"}
$xml->{"from"}
$xml->{"heading"}
$xml->{"body"}
```

and so on...