# Invisible character look up? (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, invisible

I'm parsing some files that contain invisible characters.  The files are structured strangely so that I sometimes have to find real information after 9 or 10 invisible characters.  Yeah...

Anyway, I have some files that seem to have invisible characters that my regex doesn't yet know about.  Is there some way to pass a character through a function to look up it's character code?  Since it's invisible, I don't really have much else to go on, ha.

Currently I'm using the following regular expression to find invisible characters. (found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497885/remove-control-characters-from-php-string))

```
public $invisibles='\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours are control characters. But another real invisible character is `\xA0` the non-breaking space.

Anyway to find out which is bugging you, first isolate it ([`substr`](http://php.net/substr) if you can), and then pass it through [`ord()`](http://php.net/ord) to get the ASCII number:

```
preg_match('/\W/', $str, $match);   // find first non-letter
print dechex(ord($match[0]));
```

(dechex is for printing it out as hex)

Though really, you should just download a hexeditor for such purposes.