# PHP output number with leading zeros incorrectly

Tags: php, integer

I have a line in a file like this:

```
0000000/BirthstoneEnsemble/f/0/1380152724
```

I explode by `$pieces = explode("/", $line);`

when I do `echo $pieces[0] == "0000000"` it returns false. I try to cast `pieces[0]` to string, but it is always incorrect.

```
function build_file_assoc() {
global $dir;
$assoc = [];

   $file_assoc = file($dir . 'rsnjxdlxwxwun.dbt'); 

   for($i = 0; $i < count($file_assoc) - 1; $i++) {

   if($i > 0) {

        list($parent_folder, $image_name, $tag, $size, $date) = explode("/", $file_assoc[$i]);
        $assoc[] = [
            'parent_folder' => (string)$parent_folder,
            'image_name' => $image_name,
            'tag' => $tag,
            'size' => $size,
            'date' => $date
        ];

       }
   }

   return $assoc;
}

$g = build_file_assoc();

$first = $g[0]['parent_folder'];

echo $first == "0000000"; // false
```

file contents:

```
0000000/BirthstoneEnsemble/f/0/1380152724
0000000/Thumbs.db/a/83968/1384248954
0000000/bridal images for frame/f/0/1380152879
```

Comment: Are you sure `$pieces[0]` is what you think it is?

Comment: yes. it is frustrating because visually it prints out as 0000000 which is what i expected. under the hood tho, that is apparently not the case.

Comment: Have you tried using strict comparison `===`?

Comment: updated question with full code. yes, i have tried ==, ===, casting both sides to string, etc..

Comment: @StephenKnoth: What does `var_dump($line);` output?

Comment: ["parent_folder"]=> string(15) "0000000"

i am guessing this is the issue.

Comment: did you try `var_dump($pieces[0])`? `string(15)` means there's 15 chars/bytes worth of data, but "0000000" should only be a string(7).

Comment: Ohhh, hidden spaces are a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

Try print array print_r($pieces) and you will see what is saved in specific fields after exlode.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the code from your question, it works:

```
<?php 
$line = '0000000/BirthstoneEnsemble/f/0/1380152724';
$pieces = explode("/", $line);

echo var_dump($pieces[0] == "0000000"); //true
 ?>
```

Comment: the lines in the file are not wrapped in quotes.. your example makes the entire thing a string

Comment: @StephenKnoth Yes but I wrote it *before* you posted full source. Never the less, `file()` probably returns an array of strings. You can test this with `var_dump($first);`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the identical comparison operator and type cast `pieces[0]` as a string.

```
$line = '0000000/BirthstoneEnsemble/f/0/1380152724';

$pieces = explode('/',$line);

//echo '<pre>',print_r($pieces),'</pre>';

if((string)$pieces[0]==='0000000'){
    echo true;
}else{
    echo false;
}
// output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**var_dump**

Check the actual value of your *piece*, since it's possible that you have a space or a tab character in there - var_dump will show it for you.

**similar issue**

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497928/1734033).