# PHP string comparison won't match seemingly identical string

Tags: php

I am scraping the DOM of a static site with PHP and pulling out specific bit's of data so I can put stuff into a database.

For this example I am storing the inner HTML of an element to `$domString`, I can see the string is 'Description', but when I compare `$domString` to 'Description' in the code there isn't a match.

```
if($domString == 'Description') {
    // This is not happening, even though I know
    // $domString contains 'Description' :(
}
```

I have striped whitespace and stuff, when I `var_dump()` them both out I get this:

```
string(45) "Description"
string(11) "Description"
```

Running them both through `bin2hex()` as Álvaro G. Vicario suggests returns the following two values respectively:

```
3c74642076616c69676e3d22746f702220636f6c7370616e3d2232223e4465736372697074696f6e3c2f74643e
4465736372697074696f6e
```

I need a way to strip wahtever is beefing that first string out.

Comment: what if u do `trim($domString) == 'Description'` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i guess this isnt the problem, because usually whitespaces are shown in `var_dump();`

Comment: This might happen if the two strings have different encoding

Comment: Are there any soft hyphen chars in there?

Comment: try `mb_detect_encoding($str)` for both of the string, then use `mb_convert_encoding(domString, /*same_encoding*/)` to convert both of them to the same encoding and see if they are still identical.

Comment: @KraneBird Both come back with 'ASCII'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number in parenthesis is the total byte count. Obviously, a 45-byte string cannot be identical to a 11-byte one.

You can use [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) to inspect the exact bytes. I also suggest you don't see the output as HTML—In most browsers you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

**Edit:** asking why two given strings render the same words after being processed by a web browser is better answered by actually looking at the real raw data (as opposed to just looking at the output produced by the browser).

**Edit #2:**

```
var_dump( hex2bin('3c74642077696474683d223832222076616c69676e3d22746f70223e547970653c2f74643e') );
```

... prints this:

```
string(37) "<td width="82" valign="top">Type</td>"
```

Do you want to [strip HTML tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) or something? Did you see the raw HTML?

Comment: Yeh, the byte string is different. How can I make this comparison though, is it reasonable that I want to normalise this?

Comment: How can you compare two fruits? It depends on your data and your definition of equal. Is a peach different to an apple? What if you ask whether they're spherical?

Comment: I'm saying that as a human; If I see a string 'Description', and another string 'Description' I would like to get a positive match in the same way that their rendering on the screen is matching.

Is this a totally insane request?

Comment: To being with, I'd inspect the actual data. Why guess?

Comment: bin2Hex() shows: 3c74642077696474683d223832222076616c69676e3d22746f70223e547970653c2f74643e and 
4465736372697074696f6e

Comment: Good god the tags are in there?! I was dumping out in <pre></pre> tags, how come they aren't showing?

Comment: Either way, you've made me realise my mistake, thanks :)

Comment: `<pre>` will simply display white space. It isn't a non-HTML mode or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should as question why this one happens

```
string(45) "Description"
string(11) "Description"
```

Second one is 11 chars, first one is 45! Why? So there are some hidden (not showed) characters\symbols. That's why this strings not equal.

Try this one [Remove control characters from php String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497885/remove-control-characters-from-php-string)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use a regex
like this

```
    function clean($string) {
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\;\,\?\*\%\@\$\!\(\)\#\=\&]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars
}
```

Adapt it to the special char you need or not add the one you want to keep catching like this `\#` or esle `\=`