# String not correct as expected when it comes from Internet Explorer/Edge

Tags: php, json, get

I am attempting to pass some date values from angular into Laravel using a `GET` request. I dont believe these frameworks are related specifically to this problem however.

I pass the following value from a `text` input field to my API `1/4/2017` .It is exactly this value. I need to use a text field because of a Angular JS plugin I am using to pick the date.

In my PHP API I have the following.

```
$data = json_decode($requestData->data, false);

$date_object = new DateTime;

if($data->primary_reports_from_date == '1/4/2017') {
    print_r('identical');
} else {
    print_r('not identical');
}
die;
```

In Firefox and Chrome I get `identical` as my response, in IE I get `not identical`..

**Edit:** ,. after u_mulder's comment I did a `var_dump()`
I got "string(23) "‎1‎/‎4‎/‎2017" for `$data->primary_reports_from_date`
and "string(8) "1/4/2017" for `1/4/2017`.

I have tried

```
print_r($data->primary_reports_from_date.' | 1/4/2017');die;
```

And I am getting "‎1‎/‎4‎/‎2017 | 1/4/2017" in my response

I have also tried

`trim($data->primary_reports_from_date)` and `stripslashes($data->primary_reports_from_date)` but no matter what I do when the data comes from IE I cannot seem to match it up.

Am I missing something obvious with GET requests and how the data might be affected?

The issue I have is I am trying to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` but it wont work when the data comes from IE, it just returns blank.

Comment: Might be an idea to run `urldecode()` on the string - just a guess.

Comment: What if you `var_dump` values?

Comment: interesting for the variable I got "string(23) "‎1‎/‎4‎/‎2017" and for the raw value I got "string(8) "1/4/2017" , so you're onto something

Comment: I will edit the question as that is very relevant info

Comment: I found the answer here in an answer to another question ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23066553/1652535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I am unsure what hidden characters were there exactly but with this, in IE I also get `identical` as my result

```
if(preg_replace('/[^\PC\s]/u', '', $data->primary_reports_from_date) == '1/4/2017') {
    print_r('identical');
} else {
    print_r('not identical');
}
die;
```